# Does double strike work whilst blocking?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm attacking with a 1/1 Satyr Grovedancer. My opponent blocks with a 1/2 Two-Headed Cerberus with double strike. Does double strike still apply when the creature is blocking? I understand my Satyr will die either way but say it were the case with a 4/4 creature, what would happen?

Comment: The Judge's Corner on Youtube has a wonderful [video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-0s8SoBAlo). It covers almost every aspect of Double Strike.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, double strike and first strike work while blocking.

Effectively, there is a "first strike combat damage step" in which one set of double strike damage is dealt, and then a normal combat damage step, where all other combat damage is dealt.

So whether attacking or blocking, that phase always occurs, and damage is dealt simultaneously within it.

So in the case of your Grovedancer:

> - First strike damage step
>
>   - Two-Headed Puppy deals 1 damage to the Grovedancer
>   - Grovedancer dies
> - Normal combat step
>
>   - Grovedancer already dead, can't hit back

In the case where you attacked with a 2/1 Golden Hind

> - First strike damage step
>
>   - Two-Headed Puppy deals 1 damage to the Hind
>   - Hind dies
> - Normal combat step
>
>   - Hind already dead, can't hit back

In the case where you attacked with a 2/2 Travelling Philosopher

> - First strike damage step
>
>   - Two-Headed Puppy deals 1 damage to the Philosopher
> - Normal combat step
>
>   - Philosopher deals 2 damage to the Puppy, Puppy deals another 1 damage to the Philosopher
>   - Philosopher and Puppy both die

In the case where you attacked with a 4/4 Rumbling Baloth

> - First strike damage step
>
>   - Two-Headed Puppy deals 1 damage to the Baloth
> - Normal combat step
>
>   - Baloth deals 4 damage to the Puppy (Yipe!), Puppy deals another 1 damage to the Baloth
>   - Puppy Dies, Baloth has taken 2 damage, so will now die to a Shock if it gets hit before end of turn, otherwise it'll heal up during
>       cleanup

Hope that helps